# Change label of QComboxBox without using lineEdit

Tags: c++, qt

Currently I want to implement a widget to allow user to enable/disbale all provided options of a QSet. So i took a combobox and added selectable items. So far so good, but how I can change text displayed in combobox? Currently all my items have just ItemIsUserCheckable and ItemIsEnabled as enabled flags (ItemIsSelectable is not enabled), so text of ComboBox is always text of first item. Instead I want as text "Flag1, Flag 3, Flag6" if there multiple flags and user enabled Flag 1, 3 and 6. But setCurrentText and setEditText requiring setEditable(true) or an custom lineEdit. But using an lineEdit is changing appearance. So is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem a while back, I ended up 'solving' it by adding an extra item to my model that was first in the list and always set as the current item. I then updated it's text to say 'Select items...' or 'X item(s) selected' as appropriate.